# AES Encryption! Synchronization of key between sender and receiver

Tags: angular, encryption, ionic2, aes

I have created a chat application in Ionic3 in which AES encryption is implemented. Currently I am using hard codded values for bor key and IV. I know its not a good idea.
If I am using random values for key and iv, could anyone please tell me how the synchronization happens between sender and receiver? Is there any APIs/Methods for sync?

Comment: I think its a valid question. I am also interested to know it

Comment: This is a little bit too broad.  Encryption and key transmission are two very different things.  Reliably and securely transmitting symmetric keys between two parties requires some form of asymmetric cryptography.  Have you looked at how TLS and E2EE works?

Comment: @LukePark, No I have not.